# Wireshark not showing HTTP PUT output from RawCap

Tags: http, wireshark, put

I have a custom client and a custom server communicating on `localhost` using a RESTful interface over HTTP. I'm using [RawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap) on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit to capture communication between them and then view the resulting `.pcap` file in Wireshark. I filter on "http" and I see the alternating `POST` requests and `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` responses.

My client did two `POST`s and one `PUT`. The `PUT` information does not appear; there is simply the `HTTP/1.1 204 No Content` response from the `PUT`, but the request is absent. I've opened up the `.pcap` file in a text editor, and I can see that the `PUT` request is indeed in the file.

Why is Wireshark not showing the `PUT` request? Is there a better `.pcap` file viewer that wouldn't drop the `PUT` request?

Comment: Do you have the Wireshark "Reassemble HTTP headers spanning multiple segments" or "Reassemble HTTP bodies spanning multiple segments" preferences for HTTP turned on?  If so, what happens if you turn them off?

Comment: I turned off "Reassemble HTTP headers spanning multiple segments" and my `PUT` showed up, but now I have a lot of extraneous "Continuation or non-HTTP traffic" rows.

Comment: If you right click and view the TCP stream, do you see your data?

Answer (score 0):

The complete PUT request might not be in the capture, in which case:

- if reassembly is enabled, Wireshark won't be able to complete the reassembly, and won't be able to show you the PUT;
- if reassembly is not enabled, Wireshark will show the first TCP segment of the PUT as the PUT, but will show subsequent TCP segments as "Continuation or non-HTTP traffic", and will also show all segments, other than the first segment, of all *other* multi-TCP-segment HTTP requests and responses as "Continuation or non-HTTP traffic" as well;

or there might be a reassembly bug in Wireshark.  We'd need to see the capture to determine what the issue is.